# Using sympy to solve 2nd order DE. Trying to solve for constants. Having trouble getting sympy to recognize that a symbol ahs been solved for

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

```
def A1_A2slvr():
    if(ωSquared > αSquared):
        print("Underdamped")
        ωD = math.sqrt(ωSquared - αSquared)
        α = math.sqrt(αSquared)
        e = math.e
        t = sp.symbols('t')
        A1 = sp.symbols('A1')
        A2 = sp.symbols('A2')

        #solving for constants A1 and A2
        VofT = (e**(-α*t)*(A1*sp.cos(ωD*t) + A2*sp.sin(ωD*t)) + vFinal)
        simpVofT = VofT.subs(t, 0).simplify()
        print(simpVofT)

        DVofT = sp.diff(VofT, t)
        simpDVofT = DVofT.subs(t, 0).simplify()
        print(simpDVofT)

        A1 = sp.solve(simpVofT, A1)
        A2 = sp.solve(simpDVofT, A2)
        print(A1[0])
        print(A2[0])
```

This my function. A1[0] is returning -0.1 but A2[0] is returning 1.33*A1. How do I get python to recognize that A1 has been solved so that A2[0] returns a numeric/float.

I have tried using lambdify to make it a numpy expression and it gets mad that A1 is not a symbolic expression. I have tried using subs but it gets mad that I am trying to substitute a float. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You will in general get much better responses to a question like this if you include a complete sample of code that someone else can actually run.

Answer (score 0):

I can't execute your code, but I suspect you need to insert the `A1` solution into `simpDVofT`, then solve for `A2`, like this:

```py
A1_sols = sp.solve(simpVofT, A1)
A2_sols = sp.solve(simpDVofT.subs(A1, A1_sols[0]), A2)
print(A1_sols[0])
print(A2_sols[0])
```

Comment: I get this error when I run you code,     A2 = sp.solve(simpDVofT.subs(A1, A1[0]), A2)
    sequence = [(sympify_old(s1), sympify_new(s2)) for s1, s2 in sequence]
    sequence = [(sympify_old(s1), sympify_new(s2)) for s1, s2 in sequence]
    return sympify(old, strict=True)
    raise SympifyError(a)
    sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: SympifyError: [-0.100000000000000]

Comment: If you want to run my code, ω =  40000.0, α =  32000.0, vFinal = 0

Comment: The error happens because you didn't copy the code I provided. When you execute `A1 = sp.solve(simpVofT, A1)`, then `A1` is not a symbol anymore. It is a list of solutions. Then, you ask sympy to substitute a list of solutions with the first element of such list. This behavior is not supported. Copy the exact code I provided above, avoid overriding existing variables.